# Dask, add new column based on next row

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I have this dask dataframe, the last column is the important information for this question:

```
Dask DataFrame Structure:
              asks[0].amount asks[1].amount asks[2].amount asks[3].amount asks[4].amount asks[5].amount asks[6].amount asks[7].amount asks[8].amount asks[9].amount asks[10].amount asks[11].amount asks[12].amount asks[13].amount asks[14].amount asks[15].amount asks[16].amount asks[17].amount asks[18].amount asks[19].amount asks[20].amount asks[21].amount asks[22].amount asks[23].amount asks[24].amount bids[0].amount bids[1].amount bids[2].amount bids[3].amount bids[4].amount bids[5].amount bids[6].amount bids[7].amount bids[8].amount bids[9].amount bids[10].amount bids[11].amount bids[12].amount bids[13].amount bids[14].amount bids[15].amount bids[16].amount bids[17].amount bids[18].amount bids[19].amount bids[20].amount bids[21].amount bids[22].amount bids[23].amount bids[24].amount currentPrice
npartitions=1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                     float64        float64        float64        float64        float64        float64        float64        float64        float64        float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64        float64        float64        float64        float64        float64        float64        float64        float64        float64        float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64         float64      float64
                         ...            ...            ...            ...            ...            ...            ...            ...            ...            ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...            ...            ...            ...            ...            ...            ...            ...            ...            ...            ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...             ...          ...
```

Now I need to add a new col (named succPrice) based on next row 'currentPrice'. For example:

```
row1: ask......, bids....., currentPrice(11), succPrice(12)
row2: ask......, bids....., currentPrice(12), succPrice(17)
row3: ask......, bids....., currentPrice(17), succPrice(.....)
```

How can I get this result? The dataframe is a very large, so I need to use dask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use `shift(-1)`

Dask's [`shift`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.Series.shift.html) functions in the same way that Pandas [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) does. That is, if you want to use the next row's value, you will have to use `shift(-1)`.

Keep in mind that the last value of the dataframe will be `nan`.

### Code example

```py
import dask

# Create data
df = (dask.datasets.timeseries()
      .drop(columns=['id', 'name', 'y'])
      .rename(columns={'x': 'currentPrice'}))

# Assign `succPrice` equal to the next `currentPrice`
df = df.assign(succPrice=df['currentPrice'].shift(-1))

df.tail()

| timestamp           |   currentPrice |   succPrice |
|:--------------------|---------------:|------------:|
| 2000-01-30 23:59:55 |      -0.241575 |    0.65083  |
| 2000-01-30 23:59:56 |       0.65083  |    0.742577 |
| 2000-01-30 23:59:57 |       0.742577 |    0.313805 |
| 2000-01-30 23:59:58 |       0.313805 |    0.556262 |
| 2000-01-30 23:59:59 |       0.556262 |  nan        |
```

Comment: Perfect, it's what I need, at the end I used panda in a different way but this peace of code that you suggested is much more better and is very fast. Thanks a lot