# How do I change column content based on previous row?

Tags: python, r, loops, sum, rows

Apologies. Whenever I try to make them into tables rather than into code it seems to think I have a code embedded and won't let me post this.

So here's an example of **What I have**

| ID | File | Period | Begin | End | Laser1 | Laser2 | Lead |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | longname.zip | Baseline | 0 | 30500 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname.zip | Run | 30500 | 68500 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname.zip | Recovery | 68500 | 158000 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname2.zip | Baseline | 2000 | 43000 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname2.zip | Run | 45000 | 135000 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname2.zip | Recovery | 135000 | 305000 | qfin | plethh | plethi |

Here's an example of **What I want**

| ID | File | Period | Begin | End | Laser1 | Laser2 | Lead |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | longname.zip | Baseline | 0 | 6000 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname.zip | Baseline | 1000 | 7000 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname.zip | Baseline | 2000 | 8000 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname.zip | Baseline | 3000 | 9000 | qfin | plethh | plethi |

etc.

| ID | File | Period | Begin | End | Laser1 | Laser2 | Lead |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | longname.zip | Baseline | 24000 | 30500 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname.zip | Run | 30500 | 36500 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname.zip | Run | 31500 | 37500 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname.zip | Run | 32500 | 38500 | qfin | plethh | plethi |

I've managed to filter by the unique file names and duplicate the rows required

What I can't seem to do is change the Begin and End values and segment them by Period. What I currently end up with, likely due to my row duplication is something like this

| ID | File | Period | Begin | End | Laser1 | Laser2 | Lead |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | longname.zip | Baseline | 0 | 30500 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname.zip | Baseline | 0 | 30500 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname.zip | Baseline | 0 | 30500 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname.zip | Baseline | 0 | 30500 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname.zip | Baseline | 0 | 30500 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname.zip | Baseline | 0 | 30500 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname.zip | Run | 30500 | 68500 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname.zip | Run | 30500 | 68500 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname.zip | Run | 30500 | 68500 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname.zip | Run | 30500 | 68500 | qfin | plethh | plethi |
| A01 | longname.zip | Run | 30500 | 68500 | qfin | plethh | plethi |

In both Python and R I seem to get stuck in the same place. I'm more comfortable with R at the moment but started trying with Python.

I can't seem to fix the numbers in the Begin and End columns.

In R it thinks I want it to loop over 1000 columns which i don't have rather than adding 1000 to every row. Unfortunately not all files start at 0 and there may be a gap between End and Begin columns.

R

```r
 Period = dupdf$Period
 
 for (period in Period) {
   
   End_Final = max(dupdf$End)
   
   dupdf_period <- dupdf%>%
     filter(Period == period)
   
   for (i in 2:nrow(dupdf_period)){
   
     dupdf_period[i,Begin ] <- dupdf_period[i,Begin ] + 1000
     dupdf_period[i,End ] <- dupdf_period[i,Begin ] + 6000
     
     if (dupdf_period$End < End_Final){
       dupdf_period$End
     } else {
       End_Final
       break
       }
     } 
   dupdf_period[1,End ] <- dupdf_period[1,Begin ] + 6000
   
   dupdf <-  rbind(dupdf_period)
   }
 write.csv(dupdf, filename)
 }
```

In Python

```py
for period in Period:

                row_index = 2

                for row_index in concat_df.index:
                    #for row in concat_df.itertuples:
                    concat_df.at[row_index , "Begin"] += 1000

                    row_index2 = 1
                    for row_index2 in concat_df.index:
                        concat_df.at[row_index2, "End"] += (Begin + 6000)

                        concat_df['End'] = np.where((concat_df.End >= End_Final), concat_df.End.replace(End_Final), concat_df.End)
```

Comment: This can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69000896/dask-add-new-column-based-on-next-row

Comment: Thanks. Helps with shifting the first one but not in creating the new columns.

Comment: How do you get from (1) Begin = 0 to End = 6000 (2) Begin = 1000 to End = 7000 and finally (3) Begin = 7000 to End = 8000? (1) and (2) have difference 6000 and (3)+ have 1000? Could you explain that?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Begin should be 2000, End 8000 then 3000, 9000. If I try to change it on post it tells me I have code embedded again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** Thanks to r2evans now without `rowwise()`.

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Begin_New = Map(seq, Begin, End - 6000, list(by = 1000))) %>% 
  unnest(Begin_New) %>% 
  group_by(ID, File, Period) %>% 
  mutate(End_New = ifelse(Begin_New + 7000 > End, End, Begin_New + 6000))
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 428 x 10
   ID    File         Period   Begin   End Laser1 Laser2 Lead   Begin_New End_New
   <chr> <chr>        <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi         0    6000
 2 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi      1000    7000
 3 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi      2000    8000
 4 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi      3000    9000
 5 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi      4000   10000
 6 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi      5000   11000
 7 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi      6000   12000
 8 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi      7000   13000
 9 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi      8000   14000
10 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi      9000   15000
11 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi     10000   16000
12 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi     11000   17000
13 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi     12000   18000
14 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi     13000   19000
15 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi     14000   20000
16 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi     15000   21000
17 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi     16000   22000
18 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi     17000   23000
19 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi     18000   24000
20 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi     19000   25000
21 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi     20000   26000
22 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi     21000   27000
23 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi     22000   28000
24 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi     23000   29000
25 A01   longname.zip Baseline     0 30500 qfin   plethh plethi     24000   30500
26 A01   longname.zip Run      30500 68500 qfin   plethh plethi     30500   36500
27 A01   longname.zip Run      30500 68500 qfin   plethh plethi     31500   37500
28 A01   longname.zip Run      30500 68500 qfin   plethh plethi     32500   38500
29 A01   longname.zip Run      30500 68500 qfin   plethh plethi     33500   39500
30 A01   longname.zip Run      30500 68500 qfin   plethh plethi     34500   40500
```

I named the columns `Begin_New` and `End_New`, you could change that easily into `Begin` and `End`.

Comment: You can remove `rowwise()` if you change the first mutate to `mutate(Begin_New = Map(seq, Begin, End - 6000, list(by = 1000)))`.

Comment: Ah, thank you! The `rowwise()` bothered me, but I couldn't find a way to get rid of it. :-)

Comment: (... or `mapply` works too ... over to you :-)

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful. I'm having a problem though  with some files. Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Begin_New`.
x wrong sign in 'by' argument
ℹ Input `Begin_New` is `Map(seq, Begin, End - 6000, list(by = 1000))`. This is probably when End -Begin is < 6000

Comment: Fixed it with an ifelse statement:  Map(seq, Begin, ifelse (Diff >= 6000, End - 6000, Begin), list(by = 1000))